# get rid of integer expression expected in script

Tags: bash

I know this has been asked many times here, but I have looked through all of the previous ones and still can't resolve it. This is just a simple script that checks for a running service and takes the action I define.

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE="$1"
RESULT=`ps -a | sed -n /${SERVICE}/p`
MEM=$(ps aux | sort -rk +4 | grep $1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print    $4}' | awk 'NR == 1')

if [ "${RESULT:-null}" = null ]; then
echo "$1 is NOT running"
else
echo "$MEM"
fi

if [ "$MEM" -ge 1 ]; then
mailx -s "Alert: server needs to be checked"    me@admins.com
fi
```

This is the error I get:

```
./check_service: line 15: [: 5.4: integer expression expected
```

If I take out the command for the MEM variable and run it outside the script it returns 5.4, which is what I would expect. In my script I have tried changing the "1" to a "1.0" since the output would always be in decimal format, but that did not help. I feel like I am missing something simple here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is due to the fact that bash only supports integer mathematics and your script is comparing `5.4` with `1`.

You can fix your script by using:

```
if [[ ${MEM%.*} -ge 1 ]]l then
    mailx -s "Alert: server needs to be checked"    me@admins.com
fi
```

`${MEM%.*}` will strip part after decimal point and since you're just comparing it with `1` there is no need to have decimal point in variable `MEM`.